# User-based GPU priority

Tags: nvidia, gpu, priority

I have a computer running Linux (Kubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x64), where I use the CUDA toolkit to perform some computations on some Nvidia GPUs.

I share the computer with a few other users. How can I define which priority each user has for each GPU?

Example: there are three users and three GPUs. I want user 1 to have highest priority on GPU 1, user 2 to have highest priority on GPU 2, and user 3 to have highest priority on GPU 3.

Comment: These user priorities would be only for CUDA or other use cases? Would you accept this prioritization system-wide for this?

Answer (score 1):

I "kind of" know a little bit about this due to running both a Plex server and a ML instance on the same bare metal server a few years back. CUDA 5.5 added the option to set stream priories at the driver level enabling a end-user to schedule priorities just like other activities in Linux. At a GUI level Nvidia added "performance modes" in the settings around 2016. Here's an article I found detailing this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/ . I don't know if this will help at all but figured I'd share what helped me.

Best of luck!